# Can Sandcastle generate HTML documentation with the latest MSDN style?

Tags: sandcastle

I have been using Sandcastle along with the Sandcastle Help File Builder and by default it offers three presentation styles: **hana**, **prototype** and **vs2005**.

Although the vs2005 style looks okay, I particularly like the **latest lightweight MSDN style**. Is there a way to configure Sandcastle so that is generates documentation with this style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The respective Microsoft product policies/strategies are indeed a bit weird and to some extend at odds with the move to a more open development process over recent years - [Documentation comments, SandCastle and new documentation transforms](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/devdocs/thread/91c4f5fc-d991-4f5f-ae82-47cdeec8d423) is a good rant summarizing the *official* state of affairs.

That said, there appears to be an *unofficial* (and thus legally <strike>questionable</strike> challenged, see below) solution available: Project [sandcastle-presentation](http://code.google.com/p/sandcastle-presentation/) *aims to create new presentation template for Sandcastle that will generate documentation in the style of MSDN Lightweight branding.*

In particular, it aims at integration with the highly recommended [Sandcastle Help File Builder (SHFB)](http://shfb.codeplex.com/), which addresses other deficits mentioned in aforementioned rant, namely it *was created to fill in the gaps, provide the missing NDoc-like features that are used most often, and provide graphical and command line based tools to build a help file in an automated fashion*.

Please review the SHFB discussion thread [MSDN presentation style available on google code!](http://shfb.codeplex.com/discussions/266029) for different viewpoints regarding the legality of *sandcastle-presentation* usage and make your own judgement accordingly.